# Javascript mixins

Tags: javascript, jasmine, mixins

I've been googling this all day but I'm going to have to turn to the community.  I have this code in a separate file with a couple other classes in it.

```
const withExponents = function (obj) {
  return Object.assign({}, obj, {
    pow(num1, num2) {
      return Math.pow(num1, num2);
    },
    multiplyExp(array1, array2) {
      return Math.pow(...array1) * Math.pow(...array2);
    },
    divideExp(array1, array2) {
      return Math.pow(...array1) / Math.pow(...array2);
    }
  });
}
```

And here's the spec I'm supposed to cater to:

```
describe("withExponents", function() {
    var calculator;

    beforeEach(function() {
        calculator = new Calculator();
        withExponents.call(calculator);
    });

    it("returns 2^3", function() {
        expect(calculator.pow(2, 3)).to.equal(8);
    });

    it("multiplies 2^3 and 2^4", function() {
        expect(calculator.multiplyExp([2, 3], [2, 4])).to.equal(128);
    });

    it("divides 2^3 by 2^5", function() {
        expect(calculator.divideExp([2, 3], [2, 5])).to.equal(0.25);
    });
});
```

I think I will have to do some kind of `module.exports = withExponents`?  Do I use parens? (`module.exports = withExponents()`)  And  what about importing in the test file so it knows what withExponents even is?  I tinkered with some of this stuff but it did not go well.  Corrections would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see - you should do the following:

In `withExponents` file:

```
module.exports = function (obj) {
 ...
}
```

In the test file

```
const withExponents = require(/* path to your withExponents file -> */ './withExponents.js');
...
calculator = withExponents(calculator);
```